# How to display Windows Brightness Slider on a desktop on Win-7 Home Premium 64 bit

Tags: windows-7

I don't see a brightness slider for my desktop monitor in Windows 7. This is on a computer I built myself.  It should be at the bottom of the screen in `Control Panel > Systems and Securities > Power Options` shouldn't it, or is this only for notebooks?

Comment: This feature is not available for desktops, **but**, which brand computer do you have? There may be a different way to reduce the brightness

Answer (score 1):

Brightness control is done by some ACPI magic that's only available in notebooks, and that basically controls the power that goes to the screen's backlight.

On desktops it's a little different since the computer can't control the backlight's power (the screen has its own independent power supply), however there is still hope - there is a data bus called [DDC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_Data_Channel) that allows a computer to "talk" to a display over VGA, DVI or HDMI (and most likely DisplayPort also). By talk I don't mean just image data but actual bidirectional communication (it's for example used to query the monitor for its supported resolutions and refresh rates).

It's basically the equivalent of the obnoxious/ugly UI that your monitor has, but accessible directly from the computer and programmatically if you want to.

On Windows, [there seems to be a software](http://www.overclock.net/t/1262322/guide-display-control-via-windows-brightness-contrast-etc-ddc-ci) called ScreenBright, or I should say there [used to be](http://screenwhite.com/screenbright/) since the official site now returns a 404 and [the homepage](http://screenwhite.com/) says the content was removed because of technical issues (I guess he had enough of users asking for help because the software didn't work for them).

[image: Screenbright screenshot]

It supports command line arguments, so you can create shortcuts on your desktop to quickly set the brightness at predefined levels if you wanted to. I suggest you ask someone on the linked forum thread if they still have the software and can send it to you (don't forget to check it on VirusTotal just in case).

On that forum thread there is another option - MControl, it seems to be shareware though I don't see it anywhere on their site and a person claims it still continues to work after the trial period expired, so you should give it a try.

[image: Mcontrol screenshot]

Finally there is even another utility called [MagicTune](http://www.samsung.com/us/consumer/learningresources/monitor/magetune/pop_download.html) by Samsung that seems to basically do the same, plus a horrible UI and even though DDC is standard, I wouldn't be surprised if their software was locked to only work with their monitors, but you can also give it a try.

On Linux, it's more promising - there is a command-line utility called [ddccontrol](http://ddccontrol.sourceforge.net/), despite the mostly abandoned project it still works fine and has ready to use packages for most distributions and I've personally used it with much success.

Answer (score 0):

It is only for notebooks....  Anyway you can use the high contrast themes

goto themes by right clicking on desktop and there will be high contrast themes by default

And you can increase the brightness of your monitor Manually using the buttons

Comment: But add that to the answer please! :)

Answer (score -1):

The only way I've found is to use linux and that's the reason I'm about to install the latest Ubuntu LTS version as a dual boot right now. *Yep still need windows for some stuff :(.*

Anyway the command goes like this:

```
xrandr --output <displayName> --brightness <value (0.0 to 1.0)>
```

Example:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --brightness .5
```

More info here https://www.ravikiranj.net/posts/2013/code/how-adjust-monitor-brightness-command-line/